# Describe all the submodules of $V$ considered as $\mathbf{k}[x]$-modul via $\alpha$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, modules

This problem taken from Hartley Hawkes's book (Rings, Modules, and Linear Algebra) Exercises for Chapter 5 pp. 82 number 2.

> Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $\mathbf{k}$ with basis
> $\{v_1,v_2\}$, and let $\alpha : V\to V$ be the map defined by
> $\alpha(\lambda_1v_1+\lambda_2v_2)=\lambda_2 v_1+\lambda_1 v_2$ for
> all $\lambda_1,\lambda_2\in\mathbf{k}$. Show $\alpha\in
>  \operatorname{End}_{\mathbf{k}}V$, and describe (by finding bases) all
> the submodules of $V$ considered as $\mathbf{k}[x]$-modul via
> $\alpha$. Contrast this with the case where $V$ considered as
> $\mathbf{k}$-module. (Caution: $\mathbf{k}$ may have characteristic
> $2$.)

I have proved $\alpha\in \operatorname{End}_{\mathbf{k}}V$. Now I go to second question in this problem. Describe (by finding bases) all the submodules of $V$ considered as $\mathbf{k}[x]$-modul via $\alpha$.

I know $\mathbf{k}[x]$ is polynomial field, i.e.
$$\mathbf{k}[x]=\{\lambda_0+\lambda_1 x+\lambda_2 x^2+\ldots+\lambda_n x^n\mid \lambda_i\in \mathbf{k}, i=0,1,2,\ldots,n\}.$$

Is that true if we define
\begin{array}{l@{$\;$}c@{$\;$}c@{$\;$}c}
   \alpha\colon & V &\to& V\\
   & (\lambda_0+\lambda_1 x+\lambda_2 x^2+\ldots+\lambda_n x^n) v_1+(\lambda_0'+\lambda_1' x+\lambda_2' x^2+\ldots+\lambda_n' x^n)v_2 &\mapsto &(\lambda_0'+\lambda_1' x+\lambda_2' x^2+\ldots+\lambda_n' x^n)v_1+(\lambda_0+\lambda_1 x+\lambda_2 x^2+\ldots+\lambda_n x^n) v_2
  \end{array}
?

I don't know how to finding bases to describe all the submodules of $V$ considered as $\mathbf{k}[x]$-modul via $\alpha$. Any hint to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $\mathbf{k}[x]$-module structure of $V$ is defined by:
$$\left(\lambda_0 + \lambda_1 x + \cdots + \lambda_n x^n\right)v = \lambda_0 v + \lambda_1\alpha(v) + \cdots + \lambda_n \alpha^n(v)$$

Comment: $\lambda_0 v + \lambda_1\alpha(v) + \cdots + \lambda_n \alpha^n(v)$ 
or
$\lambda_0 + \lambda_1\alpha(v) + \cdots + \lambda_n \alpha^n(v)$
?

Comment: It is $\lambda v + \cdots$. For the $\mathbf{k}[x]$-submodules, they are just $\mathbf{k}$-vector subspace stable by $\alpha$.